# Is it required to have the connector "que" in reported speech?

Tags: gramática, subordinadas

In my text this is given as a correct answer of reported speech:

> **Me dijo se alegraba** de que pudiera ir con ellos a la función.

Why is it not required to have the connector "que" after the word "dijo"? Is it really optional? Shouldn't it be "Me dijo *que* se alegraba"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say your textbook is not correct. At least I would consider it wrong, as I've never heard a sentence like that and I'm sure it's not standard Spanish (though it might be correct in some dialects). *Decir* plus a full subordinate sentence in this kind of structure is always followed by *que*, just as you said.

There are some cases where the *que* is not used before a subordinate in reported speech. One such case is when the subordinate has a verb in the infinitive, for example:

> *Dijo alegrarse de que...*
> "He said he was glad that.." (literally: "He said to be glad that...")
>
> *Afirmó no saber nada.*
> "He stated he knew nothing." (lit. "He stated to know nothing.")

This works only if the subject of the verb *decir* (or whatever) is the same as the subject of the subordinate, of course. Note you cannot say **Me dijo alegrarse*; it's simply not done.

Sometimes people do not use *que* before a subordinate with verbs like *pedir* or *solicitar*:

> *Le solicitamos no diga nada.*
> "We ask that you say nothing." (lit. "We request you say nothing.")
>
> *Pido a usted tenga a bien...*
> "I ask that you kindly..."

This is reserved for formal requests mostly and cannot be used with most verbs (certainly not with *decir*).

Answer (score 4):

"Que" is mandatory in this case, as pablodf76 states. The correct statement would be:

> Me dijo **que** se alegraba de que pudiera ir con ellos a la función.

You can omit "que" only if you are quoting, but then you need quotation marks. Thus, you could also say:

> *Me dijo: "Me alegro de que ...."*
>   He said: "I'm glad that ..."

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, in English, although I haven't seen this documented: In informal writing, there is a style sometimes used, of using quoted speech without quotation marks.  You can make it clearer by setting off the quote with a comma and/or starting the quote with a capital letter.  I've usually seen this used with short quotes.  For example:

> The nurse offered me the bedpan.  I demurred.  She said, Then I'll have to catheterize you.  I bit the bullet.

So, I could imagine something like this:

> Me dijo, Se alegraba de que pudiera ir con ellos a la función.

But that sentence doesn't have an informal tone, so it seems anachronistic.  This might be more realistic:

> Me dijo, Se alegraba de que pudiera acompañarlos.

But even if one can do this in Spanish, which I'm not completely certain of, it seems strange for a textbook.  Could you tell us the textbook, edition and page number so we can see the context?

Comment: Problem is from online digital problems to Nueva Prisma, Nivel B2.  You need an account to access it.    https://www.edinumen-eleteca.es   Chapter 8, Interactive Activities,Grammar, 2nd Problem.